# How to force a react context consumer to return non undefined value or fail if value is not provided?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

In my typescript/react application (where strict and strictNullChecks flag are set) I use some react context.

I cannot define a default value, that's why I allow undefined as value:

```js
const MyMandatoryContext = createContext<string | undefined>(undefined);
```

My context is set quite high is the component tree (logged username, selected, theme, ...) and is supposed to be set wherever I want to consume the value.

In order to reduce redundant code, I want to safely check the presence of a value.

It's quite easy using a custom hook:

```js
const useMyMandatoryContext = ()=>{
  const context = useContext(MyMandatoryContext);
  if(context === undefined) throw new Error("Must provide a value with MyMandatoryContext.Provider");

  return context;
}
```

This way, I can use the hook to retrieve the value or fail completely without having to check the presence of a value:

```js
const MyFuncComponent : React.FC =()=>{
  const myMandatoryValue = useMyMandatoryContext(); // is string for sure
  return (<span>{myMandatoryValue.toUpperCase()}</span>)
}
```

However, hooks are not available in class components (still required for some legacy code, or specific components like ErrorBoundary)

I can consume and check the presence of a value:

```js
class MyClassComponent  extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
        {(myMandatoryValue) => {
          if(!myMandatoryValue) throw new Error("Must provide a value with MyMandatoryContext.Provider");
          return <span>{myMandatoryValue.toUpperCase()}</span>;
        }}
      </MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

But I need here to check the value everytime I want to consume the value, which is somehow redundant.

Is there a way to safely (in terms of typing) force a consumer to get the non nullable value ?

I tried to hack around the `React.Consumer` type, but I don't found the proper way:

```js
const MyMandatoryContextConsumer : React.Consumer<string> = ({children})=>{
  return children(val=>{
    if(val === undefined) throw new Error("Must provide a value with MyMandatoryContext.Provider");

    return ???? // Not sure what to do here
  })
}
```

I created a small sandbox to [repro my needs](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-williamson-hwb3ts?file=/src/App.tsx):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { createContext, useContext, useState,Component} from "react";

const MyMandatoryContext = createContext<string | undefined>(undefined);

const useMyMandatoryContext = ()=>{
  const context = useContext(MyMandatoryContext);
  if(context === undefined) throw new Error("Must provide a value with MyMandatoryContext.Provider");

  return context;
}

const MyMandatoryContextConsumer : React.Consumer<string> = ({children})=>{
  return children(val=>{
    if(val === undefined) throw new Error("Must provide a value with MyMandatoryContext.Provider");

    return ???? // Not sure what to do here
  })
}

const MyFuncComponent : React.FC =()=>{
  const myMandatoryValue = useMyMandatoryContext(); // is string for sure
  return (<span>{myMandatoryValue.toUpperCase()}</span>)
}

class MyClassComponent  extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
        {(myMandatoryValue) => <span>{myMandatoryValue.toUpperCase()}</span>}
      </MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

class MyClassComponent2  extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
        {(myMandatoryValue) => {
          if(!myMandatoryValue) throw new Error("Must provide a value with MyMandatoryContext.Provider");
          return <span>{myMandatoryValue.toUpperCase()}</span>;
        }}
      </MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string | undefined>();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        <input
          value={message}
          onChange={(evt) => setMessage(evt.target.value)}
        />
      </p>
      {message && (
        <MyMandatoryContext.Provider value={message}>
          <MyFuncComponent />
          <MyClassComponent />
          <MyClassComponent2 />
        </MyMandatoryContext.Provider>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why not just write a HoC that uses the hook and exposes it to the wrapped class as a prop?

Comment: Wrapping the consumer in another component and using it ? Does this approach work for you : https://codesandbox.io/s/new-moon-i8yvsi?file=/src/App.tsx:387-760 or am i missing something

Comment: @TusharShahi: I can't (and don't want to) use `any` to preserve type safety. Can you add proper types ?

Comment: I have updated it. Since this is type string i have added it

Comment: both your suggestions sounds reasonable. Maybe you could post an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to Class Components, suggest making a wrapper around the Consumer and use it.

```
const MyMandatoryContextConsumer = ({
  children
}: {
  children: (val: string) => ReactNode;
}) => {
  return (
    <MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
      {(val) => {
        if (val === undefined)
          throw new Error(
            "Must provide a value with MyMandatoryContext.Provider"
          );
        return children(val); 
      }}
    </MyMandatoryContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

Now you can use it in your class:

```
class MyClassComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyMandatoryContextConsumer>
        {(myMandatoryValue) => <span>{myMandatoryValue.toUpperCase()}</span>}
      </MyMandatoryContextConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-moon-i8yvsi?file=/src/App.tsx:1355-1585)

Note: The children prop is defined with type `string`. There should be a better way to make it generic.